# Slice From Length to Beginning Index

Tags: python, string, slice

When slicing a string, I know that the notation is [start:stop:counter]. If that's the case though, if I have `string = "hello"`, why does `string[5:0:-1]` return `olle`instead of `olleh`?  `string[::-1]` returns `olleh` for me so that is fine but I am confused on why the first syntax does not work

Comment: `string[5:0:-1]` - here ending `0` is not considered. It should be `[start:upto stop:counter]`

Comment: Okay, so is the only alternative `string[5:0:-6]`?

Comment: No, `string[5::-1]`

Comment: ''.join(reversed('Hello')) == 'olleH'. reversed was added because many people got reversed slicing wrong.  None of this has anything to do with IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the slicing for strings is **from**:**up to (but not including)**:**counter**. Therefore, when you pass the `-1` as the counter, this would essentially say, from the last character up to the first one, but not including it. Therefore: `olle`.

See that if you remove the 0, you also get the full string:

```
string[5::-1]
```

Returns:

```
olleh
```

Answer (score 2):

If we look at each term this creates in turn:

```
string[5] doesn't exist, so adds nothing
string[4] is "o"
string[3] is "l"
string[2] is "l"
string[1] is "e"
```

string[0] isn't called as Python ranges don't do the last element.

Answer (score 1):

`string[5:0:-1]` here, ending index `0` is excluded, which is char `h`. In order to include fist char as well `string[5::-1]`

```
a[start:stop]  # items start through stop-1
a[start:]      # items start through the rest of the array
a[:stop]       # items from the beginning through stop-1
a[:]           # a copy of the whole array
```

Comment: Okay, so is the only alternative `string[5:0:-6]`?

Comment: Please see my answer. The alternative would be to avoid the `0` altogether and use `string[5::-1]`

Comment: @J4102 alternative is `string[5::-1]`

Comment: Oh oops. I meant to say string[5:-6:-1]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see,index `5` is out of range:

```
string = "hello"
#         01234
print(string[5:0:-1])
```

But that's okay, python will handle it by ignoring it.

Like:

```
print(string[100:0:-1])
```

Output:

```
olle
```

You know that in slices like `string[0, 3]`, it will return `'hel'` (the index `3` is not included), so same goes for backward slicing, the stop index is not included.

Your stop index is `0`, which is the `'h'`, and so, the output doesn't include the `'h'`.

---

**If what you want is to reverse the string, you can:**

```
print(string[::-1])
```

**Output:**

```
olleh
```